# Combobox change the displayed item c#

Tags: c#, select, combobox

I have a combobox and a Dictionary<string, double> as Binding Source from which I can choose an item and equip an instance with the selected item

```
comboBoxNutzungsart.DataSource = new BindingSource(Zordnung.dieListe, 
comboBoxNutzungsart.DisplayMember = "Key";
comboBoxNutzungsart.ValueMember = "Value";
```

lets assume I chose the same instance which I already gave a value, now I want the combobox to show me the item.

Example of what I mean: Person has the attribute colour and the combobox contains the items "green, yellow, red, blue" at first the attribute for colour is for every person null. (up until here there is no problem)

I chose for Person 1 the colour red. when I choose Person 1 again I want the combobox to show me the colour red.

I think there might be problem because of the BindingSource.

for better a better understanding:

```
....
public class person 
   public int personNumber
   public double personColourValue
   public string personColour

....
public static Dictionary<string, double>ListColourValue = new Dictionary<string, double> {
{"green", 50},
{"red",  60},
{"yellow", 70}
};

....
cmb.DataSource = new BindingSource(ListColourValue,mull)
cmb.DisplayMember = "Key";
cmb.ValueMember="Value";

....
```

for personColour= null and person p1

```
private void cmb_SelectedIndesChandes (object sender, EventArgs e]
{
var selectedItem = (KeyValuePair<string, double> cmb.SelectedItem;
string colour = selectedItem.Key;
double cvalue = selectedItem.Value;
p1.personColourValue = cvalue;
p1.personColour = colour;
}
......
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't think the question is understandable

Comment: For the place where you select Person 1 there has to be a DataChanged event. In this event fetch the data associated with Person 1 and if his field Colours is not equal to null: Set the text value of your combo box to the value of Colour

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to store color value of person in some variable and then bind it with combo box.it will resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add Color property to Person. Every time color is selected, add to Color property of current Person.

Every time Person changed, set color of combobox with color of selected Person.

Of course, Person List should be stored in somewhere in DB or others else.